# how can we set the property of Viewstate?

Tags: asp.net

I am using a enum

```
 public enum WatchUsageMode
    {
        Watch = 1,
        EmailPreferences = 2
    }
```

i want to set the property of that enum in my view state in such a way that whenever view state is null return Watch else EmailPreference.how can i get and set the property?

Answer (score 2):

Create a property to encapsulate this

```
public WatchUsageMode WatchUsageModeValue
{
    get
    {
        if(ViewState["WatchUsageModeValue"] != null &&
            ViewState["WatchUsageModeValue"] is WatchUsageMode) 
            return (WatchUsageMode)ViewState["WatchUsageModeValue"];
        else
            return null;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["WatchUsageModeValue"] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting:

```
ViewState["KeyString"] = WatchUsageMode.EmailPreferences
```

Getting From View State

```
WatchUsageMode get()
{ 
if(ViewState["KeyString"]!=null) 
    return (WatchUsageMode)ViewState["KeyString"]; 
return WatchUsageMode.Watch; 
}
```